# How to center image in right div?

Tags: css

The screen looks as following:

[image]

The code of lower part looks as following:

1) HTML:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="contentLeftPart">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new {ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl}, FormMethod.Post, new {@class = "form-horizontal", role = "form"}))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName, new {@class = "col-md-2 control-label"})
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new {autofocus = "autofocus", @class = "textinput"})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new {@class = "col-md-2 control-label"})
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new {@class = "textinput"})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Логин"/>
                </div>
            </p>
        }
    </div>
    <div class="contentRightPart">
        <img src="../../Images/team.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

2) CSS:

```
.content
{
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 95%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.contentLeftPart
{
    float: left;
    border: 3px solid black;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #d5f5e3;
}

.contentRightPart
{
    float: left;
    border: 3px solid blue;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

I need to stretch right part to the right until the end of the screen and center image horizontally and vertically in it.

Comment: What are all the `@` coming from? You need to tag that since it's not HTML and many of us can't generate that so won't be able to help you.

Comment: Assuming you mean vertical alignment: kill the `float`, position `absolute`, set an explicit `height`, display `block` (if necessary), declare bottom `0`. `flex` is also a solution you can explore if you are not concerned about legacy browser compatibility and support.

Comment: It's MVC and it's not important in this question.

Comment: @tesicg take a look: https://jsfiddle.net/fdLnbzvd/

Answer (score 2):

You can do with `text-center` class of bootstrap

```
<div class="contentRightPart">
    <div class="text-center">
        <img src="../../Images/team.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
text-align: center;
```

in

```
.contentRightPart
```

also, remove `width: auto;`

Comment: Remove "width: auto" and try, keep "text-align: center" as is.

Comment: It's centered horizontally only. How to center it vertically as well?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by CSS with the following code:
    .contentRightPart
    {
        border: 3px solid blue;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: auto;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        text-align: center;
        float: none;
    }

Comment: It's centered horizontally only. How to center it vertically as well?